# how can we suppress subtotals of a column in a lotus notes view

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a view in which the totals and subtotals are displayed based on the categorized column. I want to suppress the subtotals and display only totals while expanding the categorized column.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Would checking `Hide detail rows` right of the drop-down with the options for Totals help?

[Edit] I refer to the second tab of the Column Properties.

Answer (score 1):

For column values select font color same as background color. In view propeties select different color for column totals. :)